# Ceiling studs too thin

Tags: studs

I am trying to find studs in the ceiling to drill holes for a heavy lamp. I need the stud to be at least two inches wide in order to get all the screws inside the stud.

While using the stud finder I am finding that the stud is probably just 1 inch wide. Does that make sense ?

I feel like i am doing something wrong since otherwise the manufacturers wont make products that require two inch wide studs.

Comment: What type of ceiling?  Most will have 2 inch joists or rafters.  Inch and a half if measured.  Stud finder might be off or you have a type of hanging/drop ceiling.  Any chance of pushing small nails where lamp is going to check actual size.

Comment: In a ceiling, the "studs" are called "joists" or "rafters". Also, in the US at least, they're commonly made out of "2-by" material which is a nominal measurement (2 inches wide by 4 or more inches tall), but are actually 1.5" wide. I would imagine that your instructions call for mounting into a "2 by" rafter because that is the nominal specification, and that if you mount it into a 1.5 inch wide rafter, you'll be just fine. If you'll [edit] the exact make/model into your post and include a picture of the instruction in question, you'll get clarity.

Comment: "*otherwise the manufacturers wont make products that require two inch wide studs*"  False assumption.  Heavy lamp? it does not get mounted to a box?

Comment: You're lucky if the joists/rafters are in the correct spot to hang your lamp - what do you do if you need to hang it between them? (you need some sort of block/noggin to take the load between the two joists)... Saw a few good ideas over here https://www.doityourself.com/forum/electrical-ac-dc/542096-installing-ceiling-light-box-between-2-joists.html

Comment: I don't really see a question here. Please revise to ask something more specific, and provide enough detail for us to answer.

Comment: Let's see a photo of your lamp mount and of your ceiling.  Unless your lamp weighs hundreds of pounds it is probably designed to be hung from a ceiling box or from a single decorative hook that is screwed to one joist.  As others have noted, the joists are very unlikely to be 1 inch wide.  Unless you have a suspended ceiling, then you might not have anything suitable to hang a heavy lamp from.  Are there any rooms or hallways on the same floor with ceilings that are higher than in this room?

Comment: If you need 2 inch wide lumber, you either need a house built roughly 1930 or before, or you need to rip a nice big hole in the ceiling and attach more lumber ot the side of the 1-1/2" lumber you'll actually find there, then patch the hole.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are correct that "two-by" lumber is standard fare for ceilings.  What you're missing is that "two-by" lumber **is actually 1-1/2" wide**.

1-by is 3/4" wide.
2-by is 1-1/2" wide.
4-by is 3-1/2" wide.
Other sizes, subtract 3/4".

And manufacturers *don't* make products that require 2" wide studs.  That would imply some sort of pre-war construction using rough-sawn timbers.

In the early days, a 2x4 was *milled* 2" x 4".  Then it was run through a *jointer* to make one side flat, then (using the jointed side) a *planer* to make the other side parallel to the first side, then more passes through the planer to make both sides smooth.  Same thing in both axes.  Early experience was that rough-cut lumber was irregular enough that 1/2" of material would be used up in all this jointing and planing.  So the target "finished" size was the finished timber was 1-1/2" x 3-1/2".

Contemporarily, mills have gotten better at their game, and are able to rough-saw the lumber more precisely, so they're not *really* wasting 1/2" anymore.

Answer (score 3):

Most stud finders aren't that accurate within an 1/8 to 1/4" of the stud, so when you're measuring 1", the stud is probably 1-1/2", the narrow end of a 2x4.

I always get the exact location of a stud buy getting the approximate location with a stud finder and then punching a few holes in the ceiling with a small Phillips screwdriver to each side of the stud till the screwdriver "misses" each edge. Now you know exactly where it is and how wide.